# Convert US date time to Indian date time format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to convert a date to Indian format with CultureInfo as **hi-IN**. I am trying the below code, but I am not getting successful result. What am I missing?

```
//item.Value=2/27/1998 3:56:98

DateTime.ParseExact(item.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN"))
```

I even tried this:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;
DateTime dateTime;
//Set the time zone information to US Mountain Standard Time 
timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
//Get date and time in US Mountain Standard Time 
dateTime = 
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Convert.ToDateTime(item.Value), timeZoneInfo);
```

Is there any way I can get the date format in "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Comment: Please note that ``DateTime`` has no inherent format; it only acquires a particular language, culture, or country-specific format by formatting it. Thus, if your source date format is in en-US format (your comment line sure looks like it), then you need to parse it using culture en-US, and then reformat it using culture hi-IN.

Comment: Just to be sure `item.Value` is a string?

Comment: "I am not getting successful result" - what are you getting? Be precise when reporting errors!

Comment: yes its a string but in date format

Comment: Though that having been said your parse exact format is `"dd/mm/yyyy"` which sure doesn't look like it will match `2/27/1998`, let alone `2/27/1998 3:56:98` (your parse format must match the entirety of the input string - ie exact). I am also not sure what time system you are using that has 98 seconds in a minute...

Comment: as others have mentioned, the input is invalid as you have **too many seconds in your minute**. If you correct the input to `"2/27/1998 3:56:58"`, you can just do the following `var date= DateTime.Parse(item.value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: ParseExact need same format and you are using "dd/mm/yyyy" , which is not even close to 2/27/1998 3:56:98

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code....

```
 var time = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        var clientZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
        var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(time, clientZone).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dtUS = DateTime.ParseExact("2/27/1998 3:56:00", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss", cultureinfo);
DateTime dtIndia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtUS, timeZoneInfo);
```